# How do I organize detail controller webview for different URLs on a table?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

I have a static table view with dozens of **static cells** and groups inside it. I am using the `Master-Detail Application` template for the iPad. In the `Detail View Controller` I have a single `WebView`. I am trying to make it so when the user selects a cell it will load a different URL into the `WebView`, using the following code:

```
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com"]]];
```

So my question is...

Is there a simple way to make the `WebView` load a different URL each unique cell? The only thing that differentiates each cell in the table is the title and I don't think its practical for each cell to point to a different view (that would require over 80 more controllers).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you just need to have your data source contain both the title you want to display, and the URL you want to pass to the detail view. You could have an array of dictionaries, where one key would be for the title and another for the URL.

**After Edit:**

Here's an example using a table with 3 sections with 1, 3, and 2 rows. The structure of the array matches that table structure -- three sub arrays with 1, 3, and 2 elements.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *first = @[@"http://www.mywebsite.com"];
    NSArray *second = @[@"http://www.anotherwebsite.com",@"http://www.somewebsite.com",@"http://www.randomwebsite.com"];
    NSArray *third = @[@"http://www.apple.com",@"http://www.google.com"];
    self.theData = @[first,second,third];
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *urlString = self.theData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]];
}
```

Comment: I'm relatively new to this, could you go into more detail and give me an example in code please?

Comment: @Collin, I don't know what to show you, since I don't know what you're doing now. How are you populating your cells now?

Comment: They're all static cells that I created by dragging and dropping objects.

Comment: @Collin, You would need to implement tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:. It's hard to provide a code example without knowing your table structure (how many rows and sections), but you can get the indexPath of the cell selected with the above method, and use that indexPath to pick a URL from an array you create. That array could be an array of arrays, where you would use the indexPath.section to pick one of the sub arrays, and indexPath.row to pick an element within that subarray.